# mongoose $lookup always returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have already looked up some questions related to this but with no luck at all. I have the following schemas

```
const Card= new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    collectionId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Collection" },
    price: { type: Number}
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

```
const Collection= new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

```
const Transactions = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    amount: { type: Number},
    cardId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Card" },
    collectionId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Collection"},
    userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

lets say I want to aggregate transactions to get the user who paid most to buy cards and his info then I will do something like this

```
const T= require("transaction model")
const User = require("user model")
const res = await T.aggregate([
      {
      $group: {
        _id: "$userId",
        totalPaid: { $sum: "$amount" },
        cardsBought: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users" / User.document.name
          localField: "userId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "userInfo",
        },
      },
])
```

I followed similar questions answers and made sure that the collection name is correct in the "from" field (I tried both users and User.document.name) and made sure the localField and foreignField types are the same(they are both mongo ObjectId) but still I get userInfo as empty array and I am not really sure why.
A work around that I have tried is making two queries like the following

```
const res = await T.aggregate([])
await User.populate(res, {path: "_id", select: {...}})
```

but the issue is that I can't do multiple lookups (lets say I want to populate some other data as well)

Comment: After a quick look, your `$group` stage "renamed" `userId` as `_id`. When you do the `$lookup` using `userId` as localField, you do not have such field for lookup. Please try using `_id` for localField and see if titworks for you.

Comment: @ray this is exactly what I missed, Thank you!